# Eclipse connection to adb is down - Cannot execute android project

Tags: java, android, adb, eclipse-kepler, android-sdk-manager

I can't launch android project and I'm getting following error:

```
Android Launch!
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
You must restart adb and Eclipse.
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'XXXXX\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

I followed below steps suggest in other threads but I'm still getting the same error.

1. Close eclipse and li adb.
2. Restart adb and it didn't get errors
3. Start eclipse back and try to launch the project again.

I have jdk1.6.0_45 and I use eclipse Kepler.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: sometimes, restart PC is the best way to solve wired problem. BTW, let upgrade your JDK, the newest Android build version requires JDK 8 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

First I upgrade adb in eclipse. Then I got another issue seems all other not compatible with upgraded adb. So I uninstall all plugins relates to adb and reinstall all of them back. It solved my issue. Hope this will help to someone.